# cookie with no domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

How can a cookie be without a domain?
In addition, why on one site these cookies are sent and on another site don't?
Please see image below:
[image]

*important note. Call are made from a flash plugin. Perhaps this is the issue

Comment: Where are you getting that information from? Have you considered it's merely a deficiency of the specific debugging tool?

Comment: chrome devtools. i also checked on fiddler but it doesnt provide detailed information